# MS access MDB to Sqlite in c#/.net

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, ms-access

By any chance can i export the MSAccess MBD file (one table only) to Sqlite( entity framework) by using c#/.net only. I want to do it pragmatically only.

Comment: *I want to do it pragmatically only.* When you're dealing with Microsoft JET it's best to leave pragmatism at the door.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, use OLE DB provider for MS Access and Entity Framework for SQLite. Here's [an example](http://www.dscripts.net/2009/01/20/connect-to-microsoft-access-mdb-database-using-csharp/) for the Access part and [this is one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/236918/Using-SQLite-embedded-database-with-entity-framewo) for SQLite